# How should I design the schema to get the last 2 records of each clustering key in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

Each row in my table has 4 values `product_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `rating`.

I'd like to create a table to find out how many users changed `rating` during a given period.

Currently my schema looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ratings_by_product (
  product_id  int,
  updated_at timestamp,
  user_id int,
  rating int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((product_id  ), updated_at , user_id ))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (updated_at DESC, user_id ASC);
```

but I couldn't figure out the way to only get the last 2 rows of each user in a given time window.

Any advice on query or changing the schema would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra requires a query-based approach to table design.  Which means that typically one table will serve one query.  So to serve the query you are talking about (last two updated rows per user) you should build a table specifically designed to serve it:

```
CREATE TABLE ratings_by_user_by_time (
  product_id  int,
  updated_at timestamp,
  user_id int,
  rating int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((user_id  ), updated_at, product_id ))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (updated_at DESC, product_id ASC );
```

Then you will be able to get the last two updated ratings for a user by doing the following:

```
SELECT * FROM ratings_by_user_by_time
WHERE user_id = 'Bob' LIMIT 2;
```

Note that you'll need to keep the two ratings tables in-sync yourself, and using a batch statement is a good way to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, the problem is I wouldn't be able to know which users have rated a certain product unless I ran an additional query. Another issue would be in your table I can only get all product ratings by a given user instead of all users' last 2 ratings of a given product, cannot I?

Comment: @Harrison Sorry, I thought I read that you wanted the last 2 ratings for a user.  But you want the last 2 ratings for *ALL* users by time range...don't you?  Yeah, that's not going to be possible with CQL alone.  It sounds like you'd need to do a subquery, using something like Spark.